# InAppPurchase SKProduct not retrieved correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm developing an app and I'm trying to implement inAppPurchases into it, I'm pretty confident that my code is correct but when i try to request SKProducts from iTunes Connect the array of SKProducts retrieved turns out empty every time, I'm hoping that someone who has done this before to help guide me through the steps i should do in iTunes connect and my app to make this work.
i have created the app and the in app purchases within the app but I'm worried i might have forgotten a step, I'm also not sure wether i have to submit the app's binaries or not before this works. thank you.

Comment: Which type of In-app purchase you are implemented. did you configure your app for In-App purchase in your iTunes account ?.

Comment: non-consumable, and what do you mean by configuring the app for IAP @Aashish1aug

Comment: You have create in app purchase in iTunes of non-consumable.

Comment: i did that, do i have to submit the app binaries so that it works ?

Comment: @Aashish1aug ??

Comment: No, this is not required. you can test it using the Test user account.

Comment: for reference : https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial